# ToolTips for Disabled Elements (Button) in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, button, extjs, tooltip

I know, there are some other questions which are related to this question.
But no answer has the right solution.
Is there a way to show Tooltips for disabled elements in gwt? Especially for buttons.
Every disabled button, doesn't listen to the mouseevents anymore. But I want to show Tooltips for disabled buttons, why they are disabled. I was looking through the whole web, but i found nothing!

Comment: This has been often asked, but the main problem is that tooltips are handled by the browser and not all browsers show tooltips on disabled elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Disabled HTML elements do NOT sink mouse events. It's not possible to show a tooltip on a disabled element.

Solution:

- Extend the button widget and override the setEnabled method to just set a style to make the button *appear* disabled when enabled is set to false. Do not call super.setEnabled.
- When setEnabled is set to false set a flag in your class that the button is *disabled*.
- Override onBrowserEvent and when you receive a click event check the disabled flag and call event.preventDefault() to stop the click event processing. ( there is actually several way to go about this so it's just an example )

Comment: I manage it, but it's still not perfekt. The button looks disabled but the click style is still enabled. I don't know what style i have to remove (or add) to prevent this. I think it's this one (buttonEl.dom.setAttribute("aria-disabled", "true");) but the button has to be rendered. i think i have to overwrite the onRender method too! what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would probably need to extend the Button class that you wish to show the tooltips for, and provide an overwritten method for some of the related methods. A few suggestions that might help...

1. Try overwriting the listener methods to see whether the method is triggered even though the button is disabled - by default the disabled button may just capture all the listener events rather than passing them through to the listeners
2. Try making the button enabled, but overwrite the painting methods to paint it as disabled, so that it has the appearance of a disabled button but still functions like a normal button. You may have to handle some of the other listeners and events in this instance, such as capturing any normal clicks and ignoring them

See how you go.